# AMD drivers dependency problems

Tags: amd-graphics, opencl, amdgpu-pro

In Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS I am trying to install the AMD 5700xt pro drivers with OpenCL support, and now I cannot install any drivers, with [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PTQwQ8JQT8/) output. (the important part is line 415 and on)  These are the official drivers, I have tried with many flags and have looked at many other alternatives.  What could be the dependency error here?  If you need more info, do not hesitate to ask.  The system seems to have some issues with DKMS.

Comment: The log states there is an existing crash report in `/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash`. And that you should read `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/make.log` for the make errors for the DKMS package. Perhaps there’s something in there that will explain why this isn’t working for you.

Comment: nope, there is nothing in the file

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DB5bmhRT3q/ is /var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash